# Robot Framework - can we create sub test suites inside parent test suite using RIDE and how can we create it?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

We are using Robot framework for automation testing using RIDE. I want to create some sub-test suites inside 1 test suite and each test suite has its own test cases.

Is it possible to create test suites like this? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put test suites inside test suite *files*, but you can put them inside test suite *folders*. You can't have a suite that has both test cases and test suites as children.

To add a new test suite *folder* (in which you can put other sub-suites) in an existing folder or project, click on the folder or project in the left-hand side of RIDE, click the right mouse button, and select "New Directory".

To add a new test suite *file* (in which you can put test cases) in an existing folder or project, click on the folder or project in the left-hand side of RIDE, click the right mouse button, and select "New Suite".

Comment: Thank u for the answer but how we can put test suits inside one folder and how it will work

Comment: @engineer: I've updated my answer to describe how to create new suites inside an existing suite.